# Thumbnail does not fill_parent as expected

Tags: xml, android, android-xml

I'm attempting to get my thumbnail (userVideoThumbImageView) to extend to the edge of the screen but it does not seem to do so. I have the width set to fill_parent so I'm not sure why it isn't doing so:

### Screenshot:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/110503723@N07/11207214295

### list_item_user_video.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.blundell.tut.ui.widget.UrlImageView
        android:id="@+id/userVideoThumbImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:contentDescription="YouTube video thumbnail"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userVideoTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Video Title Not Found" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.blundell.tut.ui.widget.VideosListView
        android:id="@+id/videosListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/groupScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/scroll_lt_arrow" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/scroll_rt_arrow" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### JAVA:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // If convertView wasn't null it means we have already set it to our list_item_user_video so no need to do it again
    if(convertView == null){
        // This is the layout we are using for each row in our list
        // anything you declare in this layout can then be referenced below
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_user_video, parent, false); resolved the issue! 
    }
    // We are using a custom imageview so that we can load images using urls
    // For further explanation see: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/imageview-with-loading-spinner/
    UrlImageView thumb = (UrlImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userVideoThumbImageView);

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userVideoTitleTextView); 
    // Get a single video from our list
    final Video video = videos.get(position);
    // Set the image for the list item
    thumb.setImageDrawable(video.getThumbUrl());
    // Set the title for the list item
    title.setText(video.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean it doesnt stretch the height of the screen?

Comment: no - I mean it doesn't stretch the width: http://www.flickr.com/photos/110503723@N07/11195356793/

Comment: Try changing the viewpager to match_parent?

Comment: I did - still the same (as in the screenshot)

Comment: Note - I'm not trying to change the viewpager - I'm trying to change userVideoThumbImageView

Comment: OK, actually, I think you're going to have to resize your image views  manually. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your `getView` method, you either need to manually apply LayoutParams to the inflated view, or else use `inflate(myResource, parent, false)` instead of `inflate(myResource, null)` to prevent your xml layout params from being overwritten. In your case, `myResource` is `R.layout.list_item_user_video`.

Then you can use

```
if (convertView==null)
    convertView = 
        mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_user_video, parent, false);
```

EDIT:

OK, it looks like ImageViews cannot in XML be automatically scaled to fit a certain width without distortion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13925725/506796

Therefore, you must scale them after inflating the view. First you need to know the aspect ratio of the image (width/height). Since you seem to have a constant aspect ratio, you could just make this a static final float variable which will be much easier.

Then you need to know how wide the listview is in pixels. Again, you're in luck since your listview fills the width of the screen. (This is easier, because it would be tricky to measure the listview's width--you would have to do it after layout completes its first pass.) You can get the screen width in the adapter constructor with

```
screenWidth = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getWidth()
```

You can also create a single set of layout params to apply to all of your image views. In your adapter constructor:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new LayoutParams(screenWidth, (int)(screenWidth/aspectRaio));
```

You can apply these params to the image view in `getView`.

Comment: The answer you provided leaves me with: The method inflate(int, ViewGroup) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, boolean)

Comment: I'm suggesting the method with three arguments, you must be missing the middle one.

Comment: does convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, R.layout.list_item_user_video, false); seem correct to you?

Comment: I'm not sure if R.layout.activity_main is what I should be using for myResource

Comment: See update for more detail. You're not putting the correct values in for the arguments. Read the documentation for the inflate method.

Comment: I didn't do it! BTW - I was able to use: convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_user_video, parent, false); but I still can't get the thumbnail to fill to the edge of the screen (I just updated the screenshot and the source above a few minutes ago)

Comment: You're right, parent works fine as the middle argument. I think something else is also going wrong. This just gets the total list item to fit the width of the screen, but you'll also need to do something to get your image view to fill the width of the list item, as the other answer is suggesting. Maybe you can try setting it's height to `wrap_content` so its size is purely width dependent, and also set scaleType to `fitCenter`.

Comment: My bad, mixed up 2 questions. Problem was the second parameter, which should be `parent`. I see you changed it, so I upvoted. Check out this article about inflate() parameters: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Answer (score 1):

I think the image is now displayed at 100%. If you want to stretch it to the full width, add the following line to the urlImageView xml:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

CenterInside does the following: *Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).*

Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for more info on scaling.

Comment: <com.blundell.tut.ui.widget.UrlImageView
        android:id="@+id/userVideoThumbImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:contentDescription="YouTube video thumbnail"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" /> 

results in the same behavior

Comment: If you have a 4.3+, you can enable a setting in developer options called 'show layout bounds'. That way you can see if the ImageView is too small, or the image inside. Otherwise, you can use the hierarchyviewer to find out what the bounds of the views are. You might discover that one of the parent views is too small.

Comment: That is VERY cool! Thank you! http://www.flickr.com/photos/110503723@N07/11207146004

Comment: Ah, the screenshot made me realize I made a mistake, and you probably should use fitCenter.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. Using fill_parent in combination with fitCenter should work.

Comment: I just tried it - it looks pretty much the same: http://www.flickr.com/photos/110503723@N07/11207214295

Comment: Try to set the Image height to `fill_parent` as well. Although this feels wrong, the scaletype will make sure the image will be as big as the width (and then stop scaling)

Comment: Still looks the same... (this is bizarre)