# The method inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, boolean)

Tags: java, android, view, imageview, int

I'm attempting to resolve a previous issue with setting fill parameters:

[Thumbnail does not fill_parent as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361399/thumbnail-does-not-fill-parent-as-expected)

however when I attempt to implement the fix provided in the answer I don't think I've implemented it correctly. When I attempt to do so I get an error regarding the inflation argument stating: The method inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, boolean) however I'm not sure the exact parameter I should use to resolve this in order to get the ImageView to fill correctly.

### JAVA:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, R.layout.list_item_user_video, false);
        }
        UrlImageView thumb = (UrlImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userVideoThumbImageView);

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userVideoTitleTextView); 
        final Video video = videos.get(position);
        thumb.setImageDrawable(video.getThumbUrl());
        title.setText(video.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
```

### ERROR:

The method inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, boolean)

### ERROR LOCATION:

convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, R.layout.list_item_user_video, false);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter to `inflate()` needs to be a `ViewGroup`. You are passing an `int`. Presumably, the second parameter should be `parent`.

Comment: does convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, convertView, false); seem correct?

Comment: No, it should be `parent`. From the docs about the root parameter: *Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)*

Comment: A valid value for you MAY be "this" which means the view you are trying to inflate belongs to this viewgroup.

Comment: convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_user_video, this, false); results in The method inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, VideosAdapter, boolean)

Comment: second argument should be `parent`.

Comment: Thanks! convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_user_video, parent, false); resolved the issue! I'm still unable to fill_parent on the image (which is the issue which lead me here)  though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361399/thumbnail-does-not-fill-parent-as-expected

Comment: @JeffreyKlardie: You're absolutely right; I am a moron. I have fixed my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should put the parentview in the second argument of the methods signature - that is

```
 mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
```

where parent is the ViewGroup

Comment: Sorry... commonsware beat you to the punch - if you'd like an easy answer  I'm still unable to fill_parent on the image (which is the issue which lead me here): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361399/thumbnail-does-not-fill-parent-as-expected

Answer (score 1):

As user2365568 points out, you should pass `parent` as the `root` parameter. The other answers indicate you should pass `null` or the `convertView`, which is wrong.

Check out this article about layout inflation, and why the `root` parameter is important: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/